# Does videoInput guarantee rgb camera input? (Transfering image from videoInput/dshow -> Java BufferedImage)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directshow, color-space

I am using [videoInput](http://www.muonics.net/school/spring05/videoInput/) to get a live stream from my webcam, but I've ran into a problem where videoInput's documentation implies that I should always be getting a BGR/RGB, however, the "verbose" output tells me the pixel format is YUY2.

```
***** VIDEOINPUT LIBRARY - 0.1995 - TFW07 *****
SETUP: Setting up device 0
SETUP: 1.3M WebCam
SETUP: Couldn't find preview pin using SmartTee
SETUP: Default Format is set to 640 by 480 
SETUP: trying format RGB24 @ 640 by 480
SETUP: trying format RGB32 @ 640 by 480
SETUP: trying format RGB555 @ 640 by 480
SETUP: trying format RGB565 @ 640 by 480
SETUP: trying format YUY2 @ 640 by 480
SETUP: Capture callback set
SETUP: Device is setup and ready to capture.
```

My first thoughts were to try converting to RGB (assuming I was really getting YUY2 data), and I end up getting a blue image that was highly distorted.

Here is my code for converting YUY2 to BGR (**Note:** This is part of a much larger program, and this is borrowed code - I can get the url at anyone's request):

```
#define CLAMP_MIN( in, min ) ((in) < (min))?(min):(in)
#define CLAMP_MAX( in, max ) ((in) > (max))?(max):(in)

#define FIXNUM 16
#define FIX(a, b) ((int)((a)*(1<<(b))))
#define UNFIX(a, b) ((a+(1<<(b-1)))>>(b))

#define ICCIRUV(x) (((x)<<8)/224)
#define ICCIRY(x) ((((x)-16)<<8)/219)
#define CLIP(t) CLAMP_MIN( CLAMP_MAX( (t), 255 ), 0 )
#define GET_R_FROM_YUV(y, u, v) UNFIX((FIX(1.0, FIXNUM)*(y) + FIX(1.402, FIXNUM)*(v)), FIXNUM)
#define GET_G_FROM_YUV(y, u, v) UNFIX((FIX(1.0, FIXNUM)*(y) + FIX(-0.344, FIXNUM)*(u) + FIX(-0.714, FIXNUM)*(v)), FIXNUM)
#define GET_B_FROM_YUV(y, u, v) UNFIX((FIX(1.0, FIXNUM)*(y) + FIX(1.772, FIXNUM)*(u)), FIXNUM)
bool yuy2_to_rgb24(int streamid) {
    int i;
    unsigned char y1, u, y2, v;
    int Y1, Y2, U, V;
    unsigned char r, g, b;

    int size = stream[streamid]->config.g_h * (stream[streamid]->config.g_w / 2);
    unsigned long srcIndex = 0;
    unsigned long dstIndex = 0;

    try {

        for(i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {

            y1 = stream[streamid]->vi_buffer[srcIndex];
            u = stream[streamid]->vi_buffer[srcIndex+ 1];
            y2 = stream[streamid]->vi_buffer[srcIndex+ 2];
            v = stream[streamid]->vi_buffer[srcIndex+ 3];

            Y1 = ICCIRY(y1);
            U = ICCIRUV(u - 128);
            Y2 = ICCIRY(y2);
            V = ICCIRUV(v - 128);

            r = CLIP(GET_R_FROM_YUV(Y1, U, V));
            //r = (unsigned char)CLIP( (1.164f * (float(Y1) - 16.0f)) + (1.596f * (float(V) - 128)) );
            g = CLIP(GET_G_FROM_YUV(Y1, U, V));
            //g = (unsigned char)CLIP( (1.164f * (float(Y1) - 16.0f)) - (0.813f * (float(V) - 128.0f)) - (0.391f * (float(U) - 128.0f)) );
            b = CLIP(GET_B_FROM_YUV(Y1, U, V));
            //b = (unsigned char)CLIP( (1.164f * (float(Y1) - 16.0f)) + (2.018f * (float(U) - 128.0f)) );


            stream[streamid]->rgb_buffer[dstIndex] = b;
            stream[streamid]->rgb_buffer[dstIndex + 1] = g;
            stream[streamid]->rgb_buffer[dstIndex + 2] = r;

            dstIndex += 3;

            r = CLIP(GET_R_FROM_YUV(Y2, U, V));
            //r = (unsigned char)CLIP( (1.164f * (float(Y2) - 16.0f)) + (1.596f * (float(V) - 128)) );
            g = CLIP(GET_G_FROM_YUV(Y2, U, V));
            //g = (unsigned char)CLIP( (1.164f * (float(Y2) - 16.0f)) - (0.813f * (float(V) - 128.0f)) - (0.391f * (float(U) - 128.0f)) );
            b = CLIP(GET_B_FROM_YUV(Y2, U, V));
            //b = (unsigned char)CLIP( (1.164f * (float(Y2) - 16.0f)) + (2.018f * (float(U) - 128.0f)) );

            stream[streamid]->rgb_buffer[dstIndex] = b;
            stream[streamid]->rgb_buffer[dstIndex + 1] = g;
            stream[streamid]->rgb_buffer[dstIndex + 2] = r;

            dstIndex += 3;

            srcIndex += 4;
        }

        return true;
    } catch(...) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

After this wasn't working, I assume either a) my color space conversion function is wrong, or b) videoInput is lying to me.

Well, I wanted to double check that videoInput was indeed telling me the truth, and it turns out there is absolutely no way for me to see the pixel format I'm getting from the videoInput::getPixels() function, outside of the verbose text (unless I'm extremely crazy and just can't see it).  This makes me assume that it's possible that videoInput does some sort of color space conversion behind the scenes so you're always getting a consistent image, regardless of the webcam.  With this in mind, and following some of the documentation in videoInput.h:96, it sort of appears that it just gives out RGB or BGR images.

The utility I'm using to display the image takes RGB images (Java BufferedImage), so I figured I could just feed it the raw data directly from videoInput, and it should be fine.

Here is how I've got my image setup in Java:

```
BufferedImage buffer = new BufferedImage(directShow.device_stream_width(stream),directShow.device_stream_height(stream), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB );

int rgbdata[] = directShow.grab_frame_stream(stream);
if( rgbdata.length > 0 ) {
  buffer.setRGB(
    0, 0,
    directShow.device_stream_width(stream),
    directShow.device_stream_height(stream),
    rgbdata,
    0, directShow.device_stream_width(stream)
  );
}
```

And here is how I send it to Java (C++/JNI):

```
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL Java_directshowcamera_dsInterface_grab_1frame_1stream(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint streamid)
{
    //jclass bbclass = env->FindClass( "java/nio/IntBuffer" );
    //jmethodID putMethod = env->GetMethodID(bbclass, "put", "(B)Ljava/nio/IntBuffer;");
    int buffer_size;
    jintArray ia;
    jint *intbuffer = NULL;
    unsigned char *buffer = NULL;

    append_stream( streamid );

    buffer_size = stream_device_rgb24_size(streamid);
    ia = env->NewIntArray( buffer_size );
    intbuffer = (jint *)calloc( buffer_size, sizeof(jint) );

    buffer = stream_device_buffer_rgb( streamid );
    if( buffer == NULL ) {
        env->DeleteLocalRef( ia );
        return env->NewIntArray( 0 );
    }

    for(int i=0; i < buffer_size; i++ ) {
        intbuffer[i] = (jint)buffer[i];
    }
    env->SetIntArrayRegion( ia, 0, buffer_size, intbuffer );

    free( intbuffer );

    return ia;
}
```

This has been driving me absolutely nuts for the past two weeks, and I've tried variations of anything suggested to me as well, with absolutely no sane success.

Comment: Or you could use `VideoInputFrameGrabber` as part of [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/)...

Comment: I was using this, however, the software I'm developing is for work, and we'll be deploying it to a lot of people via java webstart, and we thought OpenCV was too much overhead to have clients install on their machine (especially considering the win32 install of OpenCV for JavaCV requires some tweaking of the PATH environment variable).  I realize that the pipeline of JavaCV eventually uses videoInput (through OpenCV) on the windows platform, but my boss wanted me to experiment with minimal native binaries.

Comment: Ok, looks like the author had the same doubts: https://github.com/ofTheo/videoInput/blob/master/videoInputSrcAndDemos/libs/videoInput/videoInput.cpp#L1901 I'd gladly answer your question if DirectShow didn't give me such horrible headaches. :)

Comment: What is the size of one frame of data you receive? If it's YV12 then it must be width*height*1.25, if it's YUY2 it's width*height*1.5 and if RGB24 it's width*height*3 (assuming width is a multiple of 4 so no padding issues).

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by "wasn't working"? Crashed? Got garbage pics? Try first simpler conversion: r=g=b=Y, no arithmetic at all. You should see a black and white video then (if data format is interpreted properly). After you successfully get a b/w image then start applying those arithmetic to get colors right.